# Handling special characters in Twilio API

Tags: java, sms, twilio

The SMS I send via Twilio API contain from time to time special characters like u umlaut (ü) or e with grave (è). On some phones they are broken, but on most of devices they look just fine.

According to [this](https://wire2air.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202667135-GSM-Encoding-and-Special-Characters) article both characters I mentioned above are in set.

I'm wondering what might causing this behaviour on some devices. When I send a SMS, I provide following parameters: `From, To` and `Body` as an UTF8 Java String.

**EDIT 1:**
Here's how I call the API (in Java):

```
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authenticationToken);
Account account = client.getAccount();
MessageFactory messageFactory = account.getMessageFactory();

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MessagingServiceSid", messagingServiceSid));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", phone));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", message));

try {
    messageFactory.create(params);
} catch (TwilioRestException e) {

}
```

The target numbers are located only in the USA (basically all networks).

Comment: How are you calling the API, what code are you using? Also, which phones and which networks are they on?

Comment: @philnash I provided the information you asked for in the question.

Comment: If the characters are coming through correctly on most phones, can you tell me on which phones they are broken? Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed the problem on certain iPhones (not all of them) and devices with Android (on two Galaxy S7). I'd say the problem shows up only for certain devices, no matter which OS.

Comment: If it's sporadic on the devices, then this is more likely to be a carrier issue. I'd get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and send them some message SIDs for example messages where this did and didn't work. They will be able to trace the message path and see if there is a carrier issue in here somewhere.

Comment: will do it, thanks!

Comment: did you find the solution? I am having exactly the same issue.